# Pandas datetime results are different after substract

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a following simple piece of code:

```
pd.to_timedelta(
  pd.to_datetime("2020-05-03 19:12:39.406636238") - pd.to_datetime("2020-05-03 19:12:36.508889914")
  )
)
# Result = 00:00:02.897746
```

Looks like, this result is trimmed a bit.

```
pd.to_datetime("2020-05-03 19:12:36.508889914") + pd.to_timedelta("00:00:02.897746"))
# Result = 2020-05-03 19:12:39.406635914
```

**2020-05-03 19:12:39.406636238 != 2020-05-03 19:12:39.406635914**

Why the results are different? Can I control the digits after comma for timedelta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
td = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime("2020-05-03 19:12:39.406636238") - pd.to_datetime("2020-05-03 19:12:36.508889914"))

print(pd.to_datetime("2020-05-03 19:12:36.508889914") + td)
```

The result of the second statement is `2020-05-03 19:12:39.406636238` which is accurate. When you make subtract in the first line there are more decimal points but it is not showing in the output. So, when you copy and paste the result of the first statement to the second statement you are losing some accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

pandas `datetime` is only precise to `nanoseconds`

although that is just a display formatting issue  ,the underlying calculations shouldn't be different

See , the result for yourself

```
x = pd.to_timedelta(
  pd.to_datetime("2020-05-03 19:12:39.406636238") - pd.to_datetime("2020-05-03 19:12:36.508889914") , unit='N'
  )
pd.to_datetime("2020-05-03 19:12:36.508889914") + x
# Result =Timestamp('2020-05-03 19:12:39.406636238') which matches with inital datetime
```

Answer (score 1):

The results are different because in the first case there is more precision, it's just not shown. You can see this if you look at the `total_seconds`

```
pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime("2020-05-03 19:12:39.406636238")
                - pd.to_datetime("2020-05-03 19:12:36.508889914")).total_seconds()
#2.897746324

pd.to_timedelta("00:00:02.897746").total_seconds()
#2.897746
```